# Convert Date to formatted date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column for dates and the values are like this 1181202 and i want to convert it to normal date format "02-12-2018" so i can compare it with another date however when i am trying the following it returning wrong year and date

```
SELECT CONVERT(Datetime, Text_UPD_DATE,106) -- i have tried all numbers 
 From Notes
```

it's returning 5134-01-09 00:00:00.000

Can you please advise on the correct command

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood the question, my bad.

Comment: What is 1181202, it doesn't look like a date format that is supported by CONVERT, actually to me it doesn't look like a date at all

Comment: I have a guess... But that is a very odd date format.

Comment: it's a date but stored as int in the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a total guess, based on your **one** example:

```
CONVERT(date,'20'+STUFF(Text_UPD_DATE,1,1,''),112)
```

Comment: Yup that worked, because the date is stored as integer !

Comment: Nice guess :) I couldn't figure out what the 1 was but apparently nothing

Comment: That's a very misleading name if the column has the prefix `text_` @OsamaAshraf . It would be like have a table with the prefix `view_` or `sp_`. >_<